# Sins incurring death according to Ari Z"L

Tags: capital-punishment, nusach-ari

In the Kriyat Sh'ma al HaMittah of the Ari Z"L there is a section of viduy which confesses sins which call forth particular [death](http://www.770live.com/En770/siddur/gif/121.gif) penalties.

[image]

[image]

Is there any explanation of what these four sins are (as I don't recall that any of these 4 actions incurs any death penalty) and how and why they require these particular penalties?

Comment: What's all the white space?

Comment: In order to maintain the layout I had to make the chart in Excel, then copy the content to Word, then to paint and save as a jpg. Then I had to resize the image which, I guess added to the overall size of the unused areas.

Comment: rosends, maybe easier to screenshot Excel using printscreen

Comment: May be easier to just include the text as text. Added benefit: That way it's also accessible to people with screenreaders and to search engines.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Chaim%2C_Gate_of_the_Recitation_of_the_Shema_Before_Retiring.8.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en has text from sefaria but lists the elements separately.

Comment: @rosends the text doesn't mean that failure to fulfill that particular mitzvah incurs the death penalty. It means that the particular mitzvah is associated with those particular letters of G-d's names. In other words, they are the tikkun for such a blemish. So the tikkun process is made via recital of Shema, Tefillin, Tzitzit and prayer.

Comment: Then I don't understand how the bet opening "b'vitul" works. I thought it meant "through the annulling of" and as the object of "ufagamti" meaning "And I blemished through the annulment of..."